# How to convert string to integer in amazon redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a column that holds an id, currently as string. if the id is indeed a number I need to convert it to a real integer and if not, it should be converted to a null value. I would like to run an update query on the table and create a new integer id field.

I was unable to find exactly how to determine if the string is a number

Does any one know?

Thanks

Nir

Comment: Have you posted the question at the AWS forum? There are engineers working in Amazon that might give you solid answers. Intuitively if this can't be done easily, there might be a reason. Redshift is optimized around columns -- each and every column is independently compressed and indexed. If you change the column type, the entire column has to be rebuilt. Maybe a better solution is to copy/convert it to another column. And depends on your planned use, you could also keep what's already in Redshift and do the conversion after the data is read.

Answer (score 1):

Since Redshift does not support modifying a column type, it's better to create another table with your desired schema. The way is simply inserting a varchar column value into integer and insert it into a new table.

Here is an example:

```
dev=> CREATE TABLE table_varchar_id (id varchar(24), val varchar(24));
CREATE TABLE
dev=> INSERT INTO table_varchar_id values ('1111', 'aaaa'),('2222', 'bbbb'),('dummy1', 'cccc'),('dummy2', 'dddd');
INSERT 0 4
dev=> CREATE TABLE table_int_id (id int, val varchar(24));
CREATE TABLE
dev=>
dev=> INSERT INTO table_int_id (
dev(> SELECT
dev(>   CASE REGEXP_COUNT(id, '^[0-9]+$')
dev(>   WHEN 0 then NULL
dev(>   ELSE id::integer
dev(>   END as "id",
dev(>   val
dev(> FROM
dev(>   table_varchar_id
dev(> );
INSERT 0 4
dev=> SELECT * FROM table_varchar_id ORDER BY id;
   id   | val
--------+------
 1111   | aaaa
 2222   | bbbb
 dummy1 | cccc
 dummy2 | dddd
(4 rows)

dev=> SELECT * FROM table_int_id ORDER BY id;
  id  | val
------+------
 1111 | aaaa
 2222 | bbbb
      | dddd
      | cccc
(4 rows)
```