# Reading Dynamic DataTpes from S3 with AWS Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have json stored in S3. Sometimes `units` is stored as a string, sometimes it's stored as an integer. Unfortunately, this was a bug, and I now have billions of records with mixmatched datatypes in the source json.

example:

```
{
  "other_stuff": "stuff"
  "units": 2,
{
```

```
{
  "other_stuff": "stuff"
  "units": "2",
{
```

I want to dynamically determine if it's a string / integer, and then target it as an integer into AWS Redshift.

If my mappings is: `("units", "string", "units", "int")`, only the "string" values will be converted correctly. If i do `("units", "int", "units", "int")` then it's the opposite, only the "integer" ones will work.

How do I dynamically cast the source record, and always load it as a integer into Redshift. You can assume, that all values are numeric, not null, and the attribute is guaranteed to be there.

Comment: Maybe some ideas [here](https://blog.getdbt.com/how-to-safely-convert-strings-to-integers-in-redshift/). Also related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318639/how-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-amazon-redshift).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ResolveChoices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-ResolveChoice.html) function from Glue.

```
resolved_choices = df.resolveChoice(
    specs=[
        ('units', 'cast:int')
    ]
)
```

Comment: Do you do this before or after apply mapping?

Comment: You need to do it before.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.